# SQL Flatten, Pivot, and Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am joining quite a bit of data together, but i need to pivot that data and then select the fields I want out of that query.  The data looks a bit like this:

<kbd>ID</kbd>       <kbd>OrderNo</kbd>      <kbd>Product</kbd>     <kbd>ProductID</kbd>     <kbd>MetricID</kbd>     <kbd>Metric</kbd>            <kbd>value</kbd>

<kbd>111</kbd>    <kbd>G456789</kbd>      <kbd>M12345</kbd>     <kbd>10</kbd>               <kbd>89</kbd>              <kbd>Machine</kbd>        <kbd>7</kbd>       

<kbd>111</kbd>    <kbd>G456789</kbd>      <kbd>M12345</kbd>     <kbd>10</kbd>               <kbd>90</kbd>              <kbd>MachineID</kbd>     <kbd>2020</kbd>       

<kbd>111</kbd>    <kbd>G456789</kbd>      <kbd>M12345</kbd>     <kbd>10</kbd>               <kbd>91</kbd>              <kbd>Length</kbd>          <kbd>1951</kbd>

The resultset above could have any number of Metrics (50 or even 100 or more).  The system is configurable such that they can add metrics, which means I can't really 'hard-code' anything that would invalidate the SQL.

**When the ID is distinct (as in 111 above), this would be a single row.**
The OrderNo, Product, and ProductID would also be the same, but ID is the key to the pivot.

**This is how the Pivoted result set needs to look after:**

<kbd>ID</kbd>       <kbd>OrderNo</kbd>      <kbd>Product</kbd>     <kbd>ProductID</kbd>    <kbd>Machine</kbd>            <kbd>MachineID</kbd><kbd>Length</kbd>

<kbd>111</kbd>    <kbd>G456789</kbd>      <kbd>M12345</kbd>     <kbd>10</kbd>               <kbd>7</kbd>                       <kbd>2020</kbd>        <kbd>1951</kbd>

Since there could be any number of metrics, I would want them all in that row.

NOW - After I have that all said and done... I will want to query out that resultset for ONLY the variables I need.  So, it is possible (in the example above) that I would only query out ID, Product, Machine, and Length.

I'm sure this can be done.. just confused how!  Been playing around for hours and hours trying to figure it out :(

Comment: Post your attempts,people will be more willing to help if you tried something.

Comment: The join is pretty crazy and very proprietary.  For my customer's sake, I cannot post that code.  What I can say is that I ran a select around the entire thing (crazy join result-set), used 'pivot' and queried out the specific metrics I needed.  However, what i found is that it still listed the rest of them... so the pivot won't work unless I know how to select only those I need AFTER querying out the whole set.

Comment: So, something like this:  Select ID, Product, Machine, MachineID, Length from (crazy join result) pivot (max(result) for Metric in ([Machine], [MachineID], [Length]))

Comment: FYI - That did not work ;)

Comment: @cbseo Why does that not work?

Comment: I think it has to do with all the rows of data?  When I select out only a few I then see the same amount of rows as I would have... but in the first row I get the proper Machine value... second row I get the proper MachineID value... third row I get the proper Length value (other 2 are NULL in each of those rows).  The rest of the metrics which I DIDN'T ask for show up as rows with NULL values for all 3 metrics (Machine, MachineID, Length).

Comment: Take the `MAX()` of each field in the results of the above and `GROUP BY` the fields that aren't part of your pivot list.  Also, there's nothing preventing you from posting a representative sample of the output of the query you're trying to `PIVOT`.  That's the meat of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a case statement inside an aggregation, something like this:

```
SELECT ID,OrderNo, Product, ProductID,
MAX(CASE WHEN Metric='Machine' THEN value END) Machine,
MAX(CASE WHEN Metric='MachineID' THEN value END) MachineID,
MAX(CASE WHEN Metric='Length' THEN value END) Length
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID,OrderNo, Product, ProductID
```